# I want to use Python Module in C++ Project, Module is PIL, But an import error occurs

Tags: python, c++, cpython

I want to use (from PIL import Image), but I can't this. My Python module name is Temp.py, Temp.py is TestCode.

I use Windows 10, and visual studio 2022, Python is Visual Code. version is 3.11.4

Python code(Temp.py) is

```py
from PIL import Image
from staticmap import StaticMap, CircleMarker

m = StaticMap(400, 400)
marker = CircleMarker((10, 20), 'blue', 5)

m.add_marker(marker)
image = m.render(zoom=14)
image.save('marker.png')
```

My C++ Project code is

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* sys_path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");

    const char* pillow_path = "C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages";
    PyObject* path_entry = PyUnicode_FromString(pillow_path);
    PyList_Append(sys_path, path_entry);
 
    PyObject* pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("Temp");
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_XDECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load Python module\n");
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This is Error code

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\VisualStudio\PythonTest\PythonTest\Temp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 82, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

first, I try Import Lib Path, ex, Import sys, sys.path.append(~~) but I can't..
second, delete pillow and reinstall, pillow version is latest version.

Comment: Does your script run fine normally? You don't need to add *site-packages*. Show the commands used for building and running the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I  assume you are using python release version DLLs and C++ release mode.

Add python to the system environment path instead of copying the pythonX.dll to the current directory of the exe.

There is an option to add to the environment path when installing python.
You need to check the environment path:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\<version>
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\<version>\Scripts\
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\<version>\Lib\site-packages
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\<version>\DLLs
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\<version>\Lib
```

I removed  part below and copy the .py  to the exe folder.

```
const char* pillow_path = "C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages";
    PyObject* path_entry = PyUnicode_FromString(pillow_path);
    PyList_Append(sys_path, path_entry);
```

Temp.py:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject* sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    PyObject* sys_path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");


    PyObject* pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("Temp");
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_XDECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load Python module\n");
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```